# SOA + Fusion + Weblogic + Oracle 11g - STUCK threads

Tags: oracle-11g

This is sort of a last-ditch effort.  We have Oracle SOA on Fusion, 11.1.1.5.0 (+ patches on a separate server) running, and nearing the point where we're taking it into production.  I've posted on OTN and talked to numerous folks at Oracle about this problem, but no one can seem to help me.

When under production-level load (simulating about 1 request every 30 seconds) Weblogic encounters STUCK threads and SOA simply stops processing composite instances.  The composite that fails changes from time to time, and the logs indicate that deadlocked thread is trying to load a WSDL or referenced schema file in MDS.  We have several shared schema and WSDL files across many composites on multiple partitions.  Each SOA partition has its own MDS repository.  The end result is that the Weblogic server needs to be restarted before processing can proceed.  There's nothing logged in the audit trail and nothing blatantly evident in the server's diagnostics logs.  I upped the logging to the most verbose level, and can't personally see a pattern.  I have since given Oracle the best possible logs and thread dumps available.

In the audit trail, I can click into the faulting mediator/composite for details, and the call graph shows that it calls the related service, but there's no link, and viewing the invoked composite in EM does not show an entry related to that invocation.

Is this a familiar symptom to anyone?

Comment: OTN is just a self help forum and doesn't provide professional support. If you bought that expensive products open up SRs. If that doesn't help make sure to escalate it so that your SR gets enough attention. Add to your business case that you have to switch to the IBM Process Server if you don't get a solution...

Comment: Yes, I understand and SRs with Oracle tend to get closed when they don't get enough attention by Oracle staff (ie, the logs they produce don't give them enough information to solve the problem).

Comment: No. They don't close them as long as you provide the information they request. However you can escalate the SR if your are not happy with the solution or if you are unsatisfied about the progress. They should tell you what logs they need, what logging level you should activate, etc..

Comment: Escalating this particular issue hasn't yielded any relief.  As I said, my posting this on SO is a "last-ditch effort."

Comment: I don't have access to the Oracle Support anymore. You can escalate it several levels. You have to make sure that your OS is certified and running in a certified enviroment. If you use VMWare and they don't support it, then install it directly on a certified box. Using their Unbreakable Linux or Solaris would make it sure that its still their problem. ;)

Comment: We're certified.  They are still looking into the problem.  Our client wanted the service available last week.  See my problem?

Comment: Hmm. I see and I know that SRs can take a lot of time. You should check with your Oracle Consultant if you could increase the servity to 1 even though its meant for production systems only.

Comment: `strace` the processes. What are they waiting on?

Comment: The issue isn't consistently reproducible, and running strace on Weblogic doesn't seem like it would give much useful info.  I have no idea what the holdup is.

Answer (score 1):

Should be addressed by patch 12573835.  Hopefully fixed for good in 12.x.

Edit - patch 12573835 is moderated & password-protected on support.oracle.com.  Its recommended only for BPM customers, which we are not, so no support has been given.  We have applied the January SOA critical patch and are still seeing the issue under load ("load" meaning 2 requests per minute, not much of a load but whatever, we can disagree).  So, there is no acceptable solution at the moment.